# Create hyperlink to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long list of names in my "Main Sheet". I need to loop through these rows, create a sheet with the same name and then add a hyperlink to that sheet.

I was able to create the sheets, but I can't create the appropriate hyperlink to the matching sheet.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
    'HERE, I COUNT HOW MANY INDIDUAL ROWS THERE ARE IN COLUMN A'''

    Sheets("MainSheet").Range("A1").Select

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    Total = Selection.Count 

    'here, I copy the cell value and create a new sheet, using the cell value as the name

    'Since some cells had more than 31 characters, I had to create a code to only take the first 30 characters

    For i = Total To 1 Step -1

        Sheets("MainSheet").Cells(i, 1).Select

        Take = Left(ActiveCell, 30)

        Sheets.Add.Name = Take

        Worksheets("MainSheet").Activate

        Worksheets("MainSheet").Cells(i, 1).Select

    Next
```

The code works.

I now need to loop through the same list and create the appropriate hyperlink.

Here's an example of the rows:

> Temperature Probe and Data Sensor A1
>   Temperature Probe and Data Sensor A2
>   Temperature Probe and Data Sensor A3
>   Temperature Probe and Data Sensor A4
>   Air and Pressure Sensor A1

All of these will have their own sheet, but I would want to click on the cell value to bring me directly to that sheet, without having to manually search through 200+ sheets. In short, the mainsheet will act like a directory to the rest of the Excel workbook.

Answer (score 0):

To link in the same workbook, use a formula with this format, =HYPERLINK("[Workbook]Worksheet!A1", "Link Text"). For more info see [Work with hyperlinks in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/work-with-hyperlinks-in-excel-7fc80d8d-68f9-482f-ab01-584c44d72b3e).

You can even make the formula find the workbook name, assuming the workbook name and file path don't include any square brackets. For more info see [this page](https://www.exceltip.com/excel-tools/cell-function-returns-sheet-name-workbook-name-and-path.html). The formula is `=HYPERLINK(MID(CELL("filename"), FIND("[",CELL("filename")), (FIND("]",CELL("filename")))-FIND("[",CELL("filename"))+1) &A5 &"!A1", "Link Text")`. Change the last part of that formula, where `A5` is a cell with a worksheet name, `A1` is the link's target, and `Link Text` is any text or a cell reference.

If you paste the formula with code, then use two quotation marks to paste one quotation mark in the formula, `ActiveCell.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(MID(CELL(""filename""), FIND(""["",CELL(""filename"")), (FIND(""]"",CELL(""filename"")))-FIND(""["",CELL(""filename""))+1) &A5 &""!A1"", ""Link Text"")"`.

**Or...** Here's a post about how to [add a table of contents to your workbook](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2011/01/13/add-a-table-of-contents-to-your-workbook-its-easy-i-promise/). Maybe you can just save and run a separate macro.